# Issues executing an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building a Facebook messenger bot. I got to a point where I need to show a webview. This webview does some payment processing and on success, I call a Messenger SDK's function to close the webview and then do an Ajax call to continue messaging the user. Now I have an issue, the webview does not close until the ajax has finished executing i.e. sending the messages to the user. If I place the Messenger close function outside the ajax call, the webview closes but the ajax is not executed. Please how do I close the webview and then continue executing the ajax request.This is what I am currently doing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/api/payment/'+userId+'/'+payRef,
    data: 'userId='+userId,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at `beforeSend` method  [in the jQuery Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can solve your problem, but you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/api/payment/'+userId+'/'+payRef,
    data: 'userId='+userId,
    beforeSend: function() {
        MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser();
    },    
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }})
```

In theory, the window will close before the request init.

Comment: This does not work. The webview closes but the ajax request is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood right, but did you try the `beforeSend` and `complete` functions from ajax?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/api/payment/'+userId+'/'+payRef,
    data: 'userId='+userId,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
    // Action before send the request to the url
    },
    success: function (data) {
    // Action if the process in the url url don't throw any errors
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    // Action when the request is returned to application
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // I would recommend you always use the error function. 
    }
})
```

Comment: This does not work. The webview closes but the ajax request is not executed

Comment: How about to close the modal only when the complete functions is called?
The ajax will run the url: '/api/payment/'+userId+'/'+payRef and if no errors happens, the complete function will be called, then you close the modal.